# Let $A=B\oplus C$. If $X\subset A$, $V\not\subset B$, $\dim(A)\neq\dim(C)$ is then $\dim(V)>\dim(A)-\dim(B)$?

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $A=B\oplus C$ with $\dim(A)=\dim(B)+\dim(C)$ and $C$ being the complementary vector space to $B$. If $V\subset A$, $\dim(A)\neq\dim(C)$ and $V\not\subset B$, does that necessarily imply $\dim(V)>\dim(A)-\dim(B)$?

Comment: All $V$ needs is one vector $\notin C$, i.e., nothing prevents $\dim V=1$, whereas all other dimensions can be quite arbitrary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily, for example take $A=\mathbb{R^3}$ and $B=\text{span}(e_1),\, C=\text{span}(e_2,e_3)$ where $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ the standard basis of $\mathbb{R^3}$. Take as $V=\text{span}(e_1+e_2)$. Then $V\subsetneq C$ and $V\subsetneq B,\, \text{dim}(V)=1$ and
$$\text{dim}(V)=1<3-1=2=\text{dim}(A)-\text{dim}(B)$$

And
$$\text{dim}(V)=1\leq 3-2=\text{dim}(A)-\text{dim }(C)$$